# Do labels support model binding?

Tags: asp.net-core

When I display a value from my ViewModel into an input field (see code below) and post the form, model binding is supported correctly. This means I can find the (modified) value into my ViewModel.

```
<input type="text" asp-for="FirstName" value="@Model.FirstName" />
```

But when I display the same value from the ViewModel into a label, then I don't find it into the ViewModel after I post the form:

```
<label asp-for="FirstName">@Model.FirstName</label>
```

Do labels support model binding? If yes, am I doing anything wrong in my code?
If not, what's the alternative when I need to keep the value into my ViewModel? Storing them into HiddenFields?

Comment: The alternative is to use a hidden input field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Label contents are not submitted to the server. It is a basic feature of HTML.

Only form fields' contents are submitted when the form is submitted.